# BIRT - Change decimal separator - period v/s comma

Tags: birt

Based on a global variable how can i set the number formatter i.e. Setting comma as decimal separator as opposed to period. Also, changing Date format pattern based on a global variable.

i.e 1234.56 = 1234,56

Where can i do this? crosstab? and what expression to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers you can do it with an expression:

```
params["SomeVar"].value == 'format1'? 
Formatter.format(valueToDisplay,"0,00"):
Formatter.format(valueToDisplay,"0.00");
```

Don't know if Formatter works with Date values.